How to get a single slash in the string?
Image:

I have the following string: 'To reach the peak \\U0001fa77'
It is clear that the last part is the emoji symbol, but it has to slashes before it, so when I print the string, I get 'To reach the peak \U0001fa77', not the emoji.
How to get the string 'To reach the peak \U0001fa77' from my string?

At first make sure you have two backslashes there. If you print the __repr__() of a string, single backslashes will be escaped as double backslashes.

I tried repr(), but it did not work out(

Please show actual code, preferrably a [MCVE]. You are clearly confused about how string representation works — otherwise you would not be asking! — and that means that any description you write in English is likely to be wrong or incomplete in some way that you do not even realize.

@TurePålsson Added an image in the post, have a look please

I think this answer covers the situation that you are in. Before applying it blindly, make sure that you understand what that situation is! In particular, your string does not contain two backslashes, it contains just one! Also, backslash-unicode escapes are a thing in string literals not in actual strings. Make sure you understand the difference!

Try s = s.encode().decode("unicode_escape")

Using Raw Strings
Raw strings (prefixed with r before the opening quotation mark) ignore backslashes within the string. try this
original_string = r'To reach the peak \U0001fa77'
print(original_string)  # Output: To reach the peak \U0001fa77


How to convert a string to a raw string?

@AnnaDenisova you put an 'r' before the quotes: "normal string" and r"raw string". It's just for literals, though. Both will result in a str object.

@Friedrich I added the picture, maybe that would be useful

You may try the following:
str = 'To reach the peak \U0001fa77'
    
print(str)

output:
To reach the peak 
for more information on escape characters, you may refer the following page:
enter link description here

In my case the string is 'To reach the peak \U0001fa77', I added the picture, maybe, that would be helpful

@AnnaDenisova, when you add single backslashes in Python, the interpreter will take it as an escape character and print an emoji representing Unicode  U0001fa77.  However, if you precede this unicode with a double backslash, it will just ignore the first backslash and print the remaining characters. In other words, it will not interpret the Unicode to print its emoji.
